# Как правильно построить SQL-запрос (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы:

Первая таблица 2 поля: `id_param`, `name_param`. Строки: 1 => `param_1`, 2 => `param_2`
Вторая таблица 2 поля: `id_param`, `value_param`. Строки: 1 => 256, 2 => 586

Как построить запрос к БД, чтобы сразу получить:

```
param_1 => 256
param_2 => 586
```

Возможно ли это сделать одним запросом?

Comment: так делать нельзя, да и зачем??

Comment: Зачем?.... Хороший вопрос. По своей глупости когда-то использовал в проекте модель EAV - вот теперь вопрос - как мне отфильтровать одним запросом несколько сущностей, по определенным аттрибутам (без использования циклов php)?

Comment: автор сравните подачу результатов запроса со своей:

    SQL> SELECT trunc(date1-date2) days,
      2     to_char(trunc(sysdate) + (date1 - date2), 
      3             'HH24 "Hours" MI "Minutes" SS "Seconds"') time
      4   FROM dates;
          DAYS TIME
    ---------- ------------------------------
             1 00 Hours 00 Minutes 00 Seconds
             0 01 Hours 00 Minutes 00 Seconds
             0 00 Hours 01 Minutes 00 Seconds

учитесь

Comment: К сожалению у меня нет секретарши, которая бы красиво оформляла мои тексты. Знающие люди и без этого поймут что я имел ввиду.

Comment: >учитесь

работать секретаршей?

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.name_param, t2.param_value
from первая_таблица as t1,
вторая_таблица as t2
where t1.id_param=t2.id_param
```

Comment: Аналогично. Я знаю для чего join используется. Но он выдаст мне 2 результата. А нужно 1

Comment: Если вас правильно понял, тогда
select (select t1.name_param, t2.param_value
from первая_таблица as t1,
вторая_таблица as t2
where t1.id_param=t2.id_param
and rownum=1
order by t1.name_param),
(select t1.name_param, t2.param_value
from первая_таблица as t1,
вторая_таблица as t2
where t1.id_param=t2.id_param
and rownum=2
order by t1.name_param)
from dual

Если значений больше двух можно функцию сделать

Comment: Да, значений больше 2-х. Заранее количество значений неизвестно... А вот с функциями никогда не сталкивался, буду изучать. Может кто-то встречал примеры фильтрации сущностей по аттрибутам в модели EAV? Magento например использует эту модель, но там сложно что-то понять...

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, для этого нужно сделать запрос из двух таблиц, либо воспользоваться инструкцией [join](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html) очень рекомендую почитать ссылку.

в итоге получится:

```
select tbl1.name_param, tbl2.value_param from tbl1 join tbl2 on (id_param=tbl1.id_param)
```

или

```
select tbl1.name_param, tbl2.value_param  from tbl1, tbl2 where tbl1.id_param = tbl2.id_param
```

Comment: В данном случае я получу 2 строки такого вида:
1) name_param => param_1
   value_param => 256
2) name_param => param_2
   value_param => 586
Т.е. массивы, в которых ключи - это заголовки столбцов таблиц, значения - это значения срок в таблицах. В мне нужен массив, в котором ключи и значения соответствуют значениям строк

Comment: ну блин, если нужно только одна строка, допишите: 

    where param_id=1

Comment: а Вы, вникните в условие полностью и тогда поймёте всё